# Postional disorder in images as i change the size of Emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I have layout with 2 images n several buttons .As the Button Press One Image Moves over Other up and down(Two images in relative layout moves one over other).as i change the Size of Emulator the images seems to be far not overlapping.. what to do.Suggestions.???

Comment: i don't know how to accept...?? it's confusing.. even i don't know how to put my code in here

Comment: when someone gives you an answer and if that answer suits your requirements that time you should "accept" by clicking an image below the down vote ( image of correct mark ). This way you helps others for correct answers

Comment: See it's 60% now..Please tell me how to attach source code here

Answer (score 0):

In your .xml layout files you have to set up the layout for different sized screens.  If you haven't created the layout files: layout-small, layout-normal, and layout-large, try doing this and changing your button placement for each screen size.

Comment: what if i changing postion dynamically...programatically.I can't use that option of Layout files